# Matching X against Y returning Z

Tags: r

I have three vectors:

X, Y and Z.

X can be a list or a dataframe, either of which would contain 156 variables, representing time with 2002 month 1 concatenated and stored as 20021. X is summary of all the months between 20021 and 201812.

Y can be represented as a list or a dataframe, either of which would contain 49,000 variables, representing time with 2002 month 1 concatenated and stored as 20061. Y is all the data from the source data, essentially financial time sheets.

Z contains the reverse order number of months that have passed between 20021 and 201812.

For each timesheet entry (i.e. Y) I want to be able to return how many months have passed since that timesheet entry. My pre-existing logic is to pass each row of Y and compare this against X, returning Z. There should never be any FALSE values. Please can you advise on the logic of creating a function, with the function able to utilise the FOR criteria. To clarify, for every row of Y, I want to compare against X and return Z.

I have already tried the following:

## Creation of overview table containing cleaned source data in correct format

```
Overview <- sqlQuery(upload_conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.Overview")
```

## Subset of one column upon which to apply the data aggregation

```
Subset <- (Overview$TS_TimeRate)
```

## Creation of list for data aggregation

```
list <- list(Overview$KEY1, Overview$ClientID, Overview$MatterID)
```

## Data Aggregation Function

```
Aggdata <- aggregate(Subset, by = list, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

## Time Series Analysis (storing result of data aggregation as data frame)

```
TimeSeriesAnalysis1 <- (Aggdata)
```

## For purposes of this question on Stack OverFlow:

```
Key1 <- list(Overview$KEY1) 

Key1.1 <- data.frame(Key1) 

Key2 <- list(TimeMappingTable$Key) 

Key2.2 <- data.frame(Key2) 

for (i in 1:nrow(Key1.1)) { 
count <- date_difference_months(Key1.1,Key2.2)
} 

date_difference_months <- function(x, y) { return(x==y) }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Consider providing an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Overview <- sqlQuery(upload_conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.Overview")

Subset <- (Overview$TS_TimeRate)

list <- list(Overview$KEY1, Overview$ClientID, Overview$MatterID)

Aggdata <- aggregate(Subset, by = list, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

TimeSeriesAnalysis1 <- (Aggdata)

Key1 <- list(Overview$KEY1)
Key1.1 <- data.frame(Key1)
Key2 <- list(TimeMappingTable$Key)
Key2.2 <- data.frame(Key2)

for (i in 1:nrow(Key1.1)) {
    count <- date_difference_months(Key1,Key2)}

date_difference_months <- function(x, y) {
    return(x==y)
}

Comment: Hope this helps, apologies the formatting is not so good.

Comment: Please note that I have already pre-calculated the date difference in Excel, therefore this question is not regarding the calculation of date difference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To increase your chance of getting a response, please edit your question as @andrew_reece suggested (don't just put information in comments). You should also remove your email address, since answers are supposed to be public, so others can benefit and responders can earn reputation. Good luck!